# Can I insert sudo via the ^ command?

Tags: terminal, sudo, command-history

Sorry if this is a yes/no question.. 
I am reading [this unix tutorial](http://www2.ocean.washington.edu/unix.tutorial.html) and found the following:

> Repeating and Modifying the Previous
>   Command
>
> [..]
>   If you mistype leavenworth as
>   leaveworth you can correct it with the
>   following command: % ^leave^leaven

Unfortunately I don't have a computer to try this on, but I was wondering:

Since some commands require `sudo` to run, could I then write `^^sudo` to "insert" sudo to the previous command?

Comment: Get a test computer! You can't make sense of a unix tutorail with somewhere to bang out some commands. Obviously you typed this question up somewhere. If you're stuck on windows get cygwin or ssh into some box somewhere but by all means have a prompt in front of you to test stuff as you ask questions.

Comment: I have a unix system at home but forgot to start it up this morning. I'll start it up tomorrow. Promise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think using history completion is a much more universal way to do this

```
$ sudo !!
```

Most shells have some shortcut for the previous command. That one works in bash and zsh. There are various ways you can do substitution, but usually these are best left for removing or changing bits, if you want to expand it, just grabbing the whole thing is the simplest way. You can add whatever you like before and after the !! to expand on the previous command.

**Edit:** The original question was about *prepending* to the previous command which the above covers nicely. If you want to *change* something inside it as the commentor below the syntax would go like this:

```
$ sudo !!:s/search/replace/
```

...where 'search' is the string to match against and replace...well you get the idea.

Comment: So, to complicate matters, what if I run `echo Calen` and wanted to instead run `sudo echo Caleb`.. Could I then do something like.. `sudo !!^Calen^Caleb` ?

Comment: The right syntax for that would be `sudo !!:s/Calen/Caleb/`

Comment: With bash, you can `set +o histexpand` if you want to turn it off. This is what I do, because any `!` inside double quotes will trigger an error (like `echo "Hello, World!"`)

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't work for me in bash:

```
$ whoami
mikel
$ ^^sudo
-bash: :s^^sudo: no previous substitution
```

or zsh:

```
$ ^^sudo
$
```

or even tcsh, which I think invented that syntax:

```
% ^^sudo
No previous left hand side.
```

`!!` does the job:

```
$ whoami
mikel
$ sudo !!
sudo whoami
root
```

Answer (score 0):

YES. You can do that. e.g. to run the `ls` command in /root directory,
you can do that as:

```
$ ls
$ ^ ^sudo
```

The second command will execute as "sudo ls"

Mind to it that you add one "space" after sudo, in second line.

Comment: Interesting idea, but that doesn't work either (at least on my system).  I don't see how it would either, because there's no space in `ls` to substitute.

Comment: It did work on my debian system with bash version as   > GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I think `sudo !!` is the better solution here.

Comment: I guess so. I think, >sudo !!  is the good answer to this question.

Comment: In order for this (as you typed it) to work in most versions of bash, you would also have had to left a space BEFORE ls in the previous command.